# Bootstrapping Galera Cluster

Tags: debian, haproxy, mariadb, galera

We would like to use a MariaDB Galera cluster for our project. The Galera cluster works and seems to work fine.

If some nodes of cluster are down the cluster continues to work. But after a complete restart of all nodes (restarting the VMWare host) the cluster doesn't work.

I have to stop mysql and start  `mysqld --wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm:// &` on one node. Afterwards I can restart all the nodes (one by one) and the cluster is up and running. After that I am restarting mysql on the first node, so it runs the same as on the other nodes.

This works fine, but my boss would like to have some kind of script which does this automatically, so some worker who restarts the VMWare host calls this script and the cluster is up and running.

Are there any scripts for this (I haven't found any) ?
Is there any free or commercial solution for this (best with a graphical user interface)?

We are using HAProxy to deliver the load to the nodes, but it just shows if the nodes are up or if they are not.

Or is this a dumb idea and the person who restarts the database cluster has to follow the steps to bootstrap the cluster ?